# Expo in app purchase not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to react native, recently coding about in app purchase.

below is my code for handle purchase

```
const handlePurchase = async (productId) => {
    try {
      setPressedItemId(productId);
      const items = Platform.select({
        ios: [productId],
        android: [productId],
      });
      const { responseCode, results } = await InAppPurchases.getProductsAsync(items);
  
      console.log('Get products response:', responseCode);
      console.log('Products:', results[0].productId);
  
      if (responseCode === InAppPurchases.IAPResponseCode.OK) {
        const { productId } = results[0];
        const purchase = await InAppPurchases.purchaseItemAsync(productId, null, null, true); 
        console.log('Purchase successful');
        console.log('Purchase:', purchase);
        
      } else {
        console.log('Failed to get product information:', responseCode);
        Alert.alert('错误', '无法购买商品', [{ text: '确定' }]);
    
        // 处理购买失败后的逻辑
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Failed to purchase:', error);
      Alert.alert('错误', '无法购买商品', [{ text: '确定' }]);
      
      // 处理购买失败后的逻辑
    } finally {
      setPressedItemId('');
    }
  };
```

however

```
console.log('Purchase successful');
        console.log('Purchase:', purchase);
```

was not activate after successful purchase.

where am I doing wrong?

I tried looking for different iap option, I still prefer expo in app purchase as it is most simple.

Comment: If those lines aren't logging, which ones are; the `else` block or the `catch` block?

Comment: if purchase was successful those lines aren't logging either else or catch block, even finally block not working

Comment: Sounds like you may not even be calling the `handlePurchase` function then

Comment: console.log('Get products response:', responseCode);
      console.log('Products:', results[0].productId);

is logging so handlePurchase function was calling correctly

Comment: Sounds like `InAppPurchases.purchaseItemAsync()` never resolves then. There are some relevant issues listed [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues?q=is%3Aissue+InAppPurchases.purchaseItemAsync+never+resolves+is%3Aclosed)

Comment: I tried wrap InAppPurchases.purchaseItemAsync() to custom promise but I'm getting Failed to purchase: [TypeError: undefined is not a function]